# why does DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>
    <label for="rdb_disease">Are you okay?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9" class="rdb_disease">

        <input type="radio" id="no" name="rdb_diseease" value="0">
        <label for="no">No</label>

         <input type="radio" id="yas" name="rdb_diseease" value="1">
         <label for="yes">yes</label>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="disease_panel">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>

<script>

var rdb_disease = document.getElementById("rdb_disease");

function rdb_visible_hide_panel(rdb_name,panel_name) {

    var radio = rdb_name.getElementsByTagName("input");
    if (radio[1].checked == true) {
                panel_name.style.display = "block";
    } else {
                panel_name.style.display = "none";
    }
}

rdb_disease.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    rdb_visible_hide_panel(rdb_disease,disease_panel);
});

</script>
```

I see an error message (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null)
I ithink the problem is (getElementsByTagName)
But anyway it cannot reach Element
what is the problem i want anser in thes problem

Comment: There is a lot going on here that is not correct (Pretty much everything). At what stage coding this did you begin to debug?

Comment: this line rdb_disease.addEventListener("change", function()[
Noticeable
The code works if used getElementById .

Comment: You use `document.getElementById("rdb_disease")` yet there is not element with an ID attribute like that. You only have an element with this class.

Comment: Why didn't you define id `rdb_disease`?  There is only `<label for="rdb_disease" ">are you okay</label>` This isn't a tag. `for="rdb_disease" "`.

Comment: There's no element in your DOM having element rdb_disease. Both the input fields have name  rub_disease i.e name="rdb_diseease" , and trying to get those through 
document.getElementById("rdb_disease") is not correct . you should get element by attribute name

Comment: @Mostafa Hossny, I am having a request for you. If my answer has solved your problem, can you please upvote it as well? Of course, there is no compulsion to do so but doing so would help me increase my reputations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `for` attribute's value must be the id of an element and not the `class` or `name` of the element.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

2. You have used an extra `"` in `<label for="rdb_disease" ">`.
3. Added an id `rbd_disease`
4. `name` correction for `<input>` tag. `diseease` => `disease`
5. Used ternary operator.
6. Created variable `disease_panel`.
7. Changed the default `display` of `disease_panel` to `none`.

```
<div>
    <label for="rdb_disease">Are you okay?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9" class="rdb_disease" id="rdb_disease">

        <input type="radio" id="no" name="rdb_disease" value="0">
        <label for="no">No</label>

         <input type="radio" id="yas" name="rdb_disease" value="1">
         <label for="yes">yes</label>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="disease_panel" style = "display : none">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>

<script>

var rdb_disease = document.getElementById("rdb_disease");
var disease_panel = document.getElementById("disease_panel");

function rdb_visible_hide_panel(rdb_name,panel_name) {
    var radio = rdb_name.getElementsByTagName("input");
    panel_name.style.display = radio[1].checked ? "block" : "none";
}

rdb_disease.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    rdb_visible_hide_panel(rdb_disease,disease_panel);
});

</script>
```